# Infragistics controls occasionally don't render

Tags: infragistics, system.drawing.graphics

Got a strange problem with Infragistics controls.

For the most part they work fine, but every now and again, one will fail to render at runtime and I'll see the control on the form with a Red Cross through it.  The latest example is where the constructor of the UltraGridExcelExporter tries to grab a handle to the Device Context in the System.Drawning Graphics class (Call stack below - minus the company-proprietary call).

Any ideas what causes this and how I can handle it, given that the error is being thrown in the Infragistics controls?

```
Type : System.ArgumentException
Message : Parameter is not valid.
Source : System.Drawing
Help link : 
ParamName : 
Data : System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
TargetSite : IntPtr GetHdc()
HResult : -2147024809
Stack Trace:    at System.Drawing.Graphics.GetHdc()
   at Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.ExcelExport.UltraGridExcelExporter..ctor()
   at Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.ExcelExport.UltraGridExcelExporter..ctor(IContainer container)
```